# Add random number at Random time intervals

Tags: javascript, angularjs, random

The thing is I want to add random number to a variable which is initially 0 which has to happen after a random timeout until the variable reaches 100.

```
$scope.var1 = 0;

do{
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.var1 += Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 +1);
    },Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 +1));
    console.log($scope.var1);

}while($scope.var1<100)
```

`$scope.var1` always stays 0, hence it goes to an infinite loop;

Comment: So? what's your issue?

Comment: edited the question just now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get inifinity loop since `$timeout` function, that you use, is async, but your loop is sync. You have to use recursion:

```
$scope.var1 = 0;

function recursiveTimeout(){
    $timeout(function(){
        if($scope.var1 < 100){
          $scope.var1 += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
          console.log($scope.var1);
          recursiveTimeout()
        }
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 + 1));
}
recursiveTimeout()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dwypcx1f/3/

Answer (score -2):

`Math.random` is a JS function, so it has to be `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 +1);` instead of `Math.floor(Math.random * 100 +1);`

I didn't checked the rest of your code.

---

You start a new loop on every loop iteration. I am not sure about the correct AngularJS syntax since I prefer Angular2, but something like this should work...

```
$scope.var1 = 0;
var repeatFunc = function repeatFunc() {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 +1);
    $scope.var1 += num;
    console.log("num: ", num);
    if ($scope.var1 < 100)
        $timeout(repeatFunc, num);
}
repeatFunc();
```